# Updating l3kernel

Tags: updating

How can I update my package `l3kernel`? I am presented with this error `! Package l3regex Error: Support package l3kernel too old.` when I try to compile my document.
Thanks

Comment: Don't. Just update your TeX distribution. You don't want the updated`l3kernel` on its own because other things depend on it and will have been updated accordingly.

Comment: As cfr says, this depends on your distribution (TeX Live, MacTeX, MikTeX). You do not give any information about that, but most should be covered in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) I think.